# Boto3 EMR: List all tasks in Boto3 instead of list all steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, boto3, amazon-emr

Using [Boto3's list_steps](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_steps) function, I can get a clean list of all the steps that were submitted to an EMR cluster, together with the status (completed, running, etc).

However, this only seems to report on Cluster Steps, rather than Job Tasks (aka. jobs submitted directly to the cluster via Hadoop or Hive). [This link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/AddingStepstoaJobFlow.html) provides more context for the different ways to submit work to an EMR cluster.

**Does Boto3 have any method similar to list_steps(), but for job tasks instead?**

I'm mainly looking for a list of ALL jobs (either tasks or steps) that are occurring in a cluster.
I'm aware that I can parse through the log groups for each JobFlowId and JobId, but I'm hoping to find an easier way.